# Aftermarket wheels and tires and persistent mild vibration

Tags: ford, maintenance, wheels, vibration, f-150

I drive a **2011 F-150**. I put on aftermarket **20" Fuel Maverick wheels and 305/50/20 Nitto Terra Grapplers after having a 2 inch leveling kit installed** this past summer.

I've been struggling with a **mild vibration over about 70mph**. Up until then there is no problem but once I get to 75mph or so, it becomes pretty well pronounced (passenger seat shaking a little when nobody's in it).

I've had the wheels and tires **balanced probably 8 times, alignment checked and verified** but it still remains.

I was wondering what it might be and what might be worth asking of my local QuikLane to have them check on.

Comment: Have you checked the U joints for binding or wear?

Comment: I haven't yet actually. There's about an inch of dip in the front end at full crank on the steering wheel left or right... might be a case for bad U joints too huh?

Comment: Sorry, thinking of ball joints. Ignore, but no I haven't checked yet

Comment: Also - check wheel bearings etc. My Clio had a nasty vibration that started at over 70 then got progressively worse till it was constant. Turns out one of the rear wheel bearings was completely shot.

Answer (score 1):

Check the tyres very carefully for tread separation or damage.. Rotate them and look across the treads surface whilst they're rotating, I suspect a malformed or out of round tyre on the rear. This will give the symptoms your describing however I would suspect the vibration would be there at lower speeds too perhaps just not as noticeable. The tyres may well be balanced but even if they're balanced properly it will make no difference if the tyre is oval etc.

Answer (score 0):

Check your front brake rotors for uneven wear. I have experienced the same vibration symptoms before from a worn front rotor.